# AES memory efficiency

Tags: c++, memory, encryption, memory-management, aes

I'm writing a C++ program for AES encryption with CTR block chaining, but my question doesn't require knowledge of either.

I'm wondering how much of a file i should buffer to encrypt and output to the new encrypted file. I ask this because i know disk reads are quite expensive so it only makes sense i should, if possible, read and buffer the entire original file, encrypt, output to new file. However, if the file is 1gb, i don't want to reserve a whole 1gb in main memory for the during of the encryption.

So, im curious what the optimal buffer size is? For example, buffering 100mb and performing 10 iterations of encryption to process the entire 1gb file. Thanks.

Comment: "CTR block chaining" does not make sense.

Comment: Fair enough, but you understand what i mean.

Comment: No I don't. CTR is counter code which is a streaming mode. CBC is Cypher Block Chaining. The are very different. See [cipher modes of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). You need to spend some time understanding encryption.

Comment: There is no such thing as "CTR block chaining", I was and still am confused by that term. There is CBC mode which is Cipher Block Chaining mode and there is CTR mode which is Counter mode and they two are completely different modes. I though that perhaps you meant one or the other. Getting the terminology correct is important to asking a question. I did provide a link to a Wikipedia article describing many common encryption modes. I was attempting to get the mode you are using to help answer the question.

Comment: It's been like 2 days dude i don't have time to teach you cryptography.

Comment: I await your next curious comment, please teach me cryptography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who's telling you that "disk reads are quite expensive"? Unless you're processing terabytes of data the cost of IO is going to be so inconsequential you'll have a hard time measuring it. A 1MB buffer will be way more than what you need. I bet you'd have a hard time finding a benchmarkable difference between 64KB and 1MB or more.

The *one* exception to this is if you're reading a lot of data off of a really slow device, something like a NAS drive on a congested network, but even then I'd consider any effort to implement buffering to be a false optimization. In that case copy the data to a local drive, process it off of local storage.

C++ buffers input and output with reasonable defaults anyway, plus most operating systems will fetch blocks of data as you're reading sequentially in order to make retrieval efficient. Unless you have a very compelling reason, stick with the normal behaviour. There should be no need to write custom buffering code.

Comment: I'm with you with the buffer size, but "disk reads are quite expensive". I'm telling you.

Comment: True, but: "Unless you're processing terabytes of data the cost of IO is going to be so inconsequential you'll have a hard time measuring it." That's just not true, especially if the disk is, well, a disk. What do you want to compare it to other than memory speed, CPU speed?

Comment: I'll rephrase: "The IO cost is fixed and trying to build more buffering into your IO code to remedy that is going to have limited effect." That being said, IO speeds are usually more than adequate and are rarely an issue except at terabyte scale.

Comment: I think you're being overly pedantic. Yes, disk IO is orders of magnitude slower than system memory, but we're talking about processing files on disk, so it's a given that cost will have to be paid. If your disk is slow, your disk is slow. Get a faster disk if that's a problem. Buffering code doesn't make an HDD perform like an SSD.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i understand perfectly now.

Comment: Could you substantiate "C++ buffers input and output with reasonable defaults anyway"? C++ is a language, so I presume you mean a specific part of the C++ runtime. Which part are you referring to that buffers the I/O?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I mean that the C++ Standard Library IO methods have internal buffers. Generally when talking about C++ it's presumed that the Standard Library is available and is the first place to look for tools.

Comment: OK, a quick look around found this API description for the standard library: "The value of `BUFSIZ` is chosen on each system so as to make stream I/O efficient.". Each compiler seems to choose their own defaults, ranging from a mere 512 bytes to 4KiB. Not very large, but probably enough for reasonably efficient streaming. Disk sectors are often 512 bytes while clusters are 4KiB so those values make some kind of sense.

Comment: Don't forget the OS also does a lot of buffering itself, and most will recognize sequential reads and start to pre-fetch more data into the kernel's filesystem buffer. The buffer in your file-handle is there mostly to avoid making too many kernel calls. It's really inefficient to fetch byte-by-byte, but it's diminishing returns and the benefits drop off steeply after several kilobytes. Plus, small buffers are often advantageous since they can fit into L2 cache if you're *really* concerned about performance. A larger read would get cycled out before the data's processed.

Comment: You can test this with something like `dd if=reallybigfile.dat of=/dev/null bs=1024` and twiddling values of the block size parameter (`bs`). At some point `bs` becomes a non-factor despite increasing in size. Try it on a file too big to hold in memory to get best results, otherwise the second run will be against the OS cache.

Answer (score 4):

[Memory map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) the file and let the system figure out the right buffer size.

Usually the file is buffered into main memory anyway (on server and desktop systems). So the buffer size in your application can be kept relatively small. 1 MiB would be plenty and would probably not matter much on any system with 1 GiB of main memory or more.

On embedded systems that do not buffer memory it may require some figuring out what is happening underneath and how much memory needs to be taken. I would consider a buffer of about 1-8 KiB a good minimum requirement. If you go lower than that and you might want to time the AES operations as well.

To make sure you can optimize later on, you may want to keep to make the buffer a multiple of 64 bytes (the block size of AES is 16 bytes and that of SHA-2 512 is 64 bytes). In general, try and keep to full powers of two or as close to that as possible (one MiB is 2^20 bytes).

Comment: Im sorry i have no idea what that means.